# How to show that $E[e^{W_s + W_t}] = e^{\frac{t+s}{2}}e^{\min(s,t)}$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expected-value

So I am trying to show that $E[e^{W_s + W_t}] = e^{\frac{t+s}{2}}e^{\min(s,t)}$

Where $W_s, W_t$ are Brownian motions.

I had an idea that I could express each Brownian motion as a function of 
 $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and then use $Z$'s mgf to solve it. Such that,

$E[e^{W_s + W_t}] = E[e^{\sqrt{s}Z + \sqrt {t} Z}]= E[e^{(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt {t}) Z}]  = e^{\frac{(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t})^2}{2}} = e^{\frac{(s+t)}{2}}e^{\sqrt{s}\sqrt{t}}$

I am kinda stuck at this point, and I dont understand why I cant come up with the correct answer with my approach.

Could anybody help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not true that $W_s+W_t$ equals in distributions $\sqrt{s} Z + \sqrt{t} Z$. It **is** true that $W_s \sim \sqrt{s} Z$ and $W_t \sim \sqrt{t} Z$ but this does not imply that $W_s + W_t \sim \sqrt{s}Z+\sqrt{t} W_1$. For such a conclusion, you would need some statement on the joint distribution $(W_s,W_t)$. To get it right: Assume WLOG that $s \leq t$. Write $$W_t = (W_t-W_s)+W_s$$ and use that $W_s$ and $W_t-W_s$ are independent.

Comment: Of course! Then you simply get $E[e^{2Ws}]E[e^{Wt-Ws}] = e^{\frac{4s}{2}}e^{\frac{t-s}{2}} = e^{\frac{t+s}{2}}e^{s}$  Thanks!